# Opening another form and keeping the same navigation

Tags: c#, forms

I have the following issue:

I have a main form and I want to open a few other forms within the main form with buttons.
But I want to keep my navigation. this can be buttons or just menu items in the toolstrip.

Is this possible or do you need to implement the menu in each form?
I already can open another form with a button click but it creates a new form/window each time I click on the button.

Can someone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your form with the `IsMdiContainer` property to `true`. You'll have your toolstrips on this main form. Then when you go to open your other forms, first set the `MdiParent` equal to your main form, then `.Show()` it.

So in your Main Form, you'll have a method like this:

```
private void OpenSubForm() {
    var subForm = new SubForm();
    subForm.MdiParent = this;
    subForm.Show();
}
```

That's all you need for it to be docked in your Main.

Comment: Thank you very much.
This helped a lot.

Comment: If this was the answer that got you what you needed, please mark it as an answer, and even upvote it if you would like. That way, anyone else coming to this page with a similar issue will easily be able to see what works.